# status_code from pytest is not equal to the real one

Tags: python, pytest

Here is a fastapi webapp. I got some trouble in test.

`post` in **crud.py**:

```py
async def post(payload: BookSchema):
    query = books.insert().values(book=payload.book, author=payload.author,
                                  create_time=payload.create_time, update_time=payload.update_time)
    return await database.execute(query=query)
```

`create_book`:

```py
@router.post("/book", response_model=BookDB, status_code=201)
async def create_book(payload: BookSchema):
    book_id = await crud.post(payload)

    response_object = {
        "id": book_id,
        **payload.dict()
    }
    return response_object
```

**conftest.py**:

```py
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app


@pytest.fixture()
def test_app():
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client
```

I use pytest to test my case:

```py
def test_create_book_invalid_json(test_app):
    response = test_app.post(API_PREFIX + "/book", data=json.dumps({"book": "smart"}))
    print(f"response.status_code is {response.status_code}")
    assert response.status_code == 422
```

Expected status_code should be `422` and I got `201`. I try to print `response.status_code`, and the output is `422`.

```sh
test_books.py::test_create_book_invalid_json FAILED                      [100%]response.status_code is 422

test_books.py:20 (test_create_book_invalid_json)
201 != 422

Expected :422
Actual   :201
```

Comment: Please share the code behind your api endpoint, otherwise it's impossible to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided information about your test client here, but I assume it is a `requests`-like one. In such case the `data` parameter expects a dictionary, not a string.

```python
response = test_app.post(url, data={'book': 'smart'})
```

This will send corresponding form data to your web app. If what you need is sending JSON, use the `json` parameter instead:

```python
response = test_app.post(url, json={'book': 'smart'})
```